# Byteman on native methods

Tags: native-methods, byteman

Can Byteman be used on native methods like `Thread.sleep`, `System.currentTimeMillis()` ?

I tried

```
RULE catch_Thread.sleep
CLASS java.lang.Thread
METHOD java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) void
IF true
DO traceln("[BMAN] Sleep: "+ $1)
ENDRULE
```

It's not working.

Comment: Any feedback on the query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot work. Byteman works by rewriting the bytecode that defines the target method for a rule. A native method is not defined by bytecode. So, it is not possible to rewrite its behaviour.